# formulate the number of revolutions required until timing marks line up

Tags: calculus

during an enging rebuild one is required to line up marks on cogs to attain the correct timing of an engine.
I am a bit more pendantic than that, I like to line up my assembly mark before dis-assembly to proof the existing setup of the engine, ie, sometimes an engine is advanced one tooth to attain special engine timing results and they will never line up.

Herein lies the issue, how many times to turn an engine untill the assembly marks line up. Some engines are totally square, their marks line up every second revolution of the crank, but many engines are not. There must be a formulation to work this out and I am hoping this forum can help.

Below is an image of the timing-train on a Toyota Landcruiser HJ60 with 6 cyl 2H motor. The timing mark can just be seen where the cogs join. Unfortunatly there is one cog missing but it is the same size as the other smaller one.

Please do not hesitate to request additional information and many thanks for any help.

http://forum.ih8mud.com/attachments/20140528_122419-jpg.1138099/

Comment: how many teeth does each cog have ? Is the one on the far right supposed to be connected to the missing cog?

Comment: Hi WW1, the small one has 24 teeth, the middle size 48 and the large one 96. Yes there is a missing cog. I should have been more precise in my op, i am looking for a formula to apply to differant sets of cogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{number of turns =} \frac{ \text{Lowest common multiple of 24, 48, 96} }{\text{# of teeth in the cog being turned (= 24 ) }}$$

in this case $n=\frac{96}{24}=4$

Comment: huge thanks WW1. How do i assign kudos to your answer and Is it ok for me to provide another example?. Manufactorers often have a big number for the answer to allow wear to spread evenly around the cogs. Ill be counting teeth later today and will post them up...

Comment: we have another real-world example for the equation and it has odd numbers in it....... Auto time gear 64.  Idle gear 51. Idle gear 37. crankshaft 32. Camshaft 64..... im not sure how to find the lcm and was wondering if you would please oblige

Answer (score 0):

prime factors ...

64= 2*2*2*2*2*2
51= 3*17
37 = 37
64 = 2*2*2*2*2*2
32 = 2*2*2*2*2

so lcm = 2*2*2*2*2*2*3*17*37 = 120768

Comment: this is why i failed at maths... I thought the lowest common multiple of the array was 1, giving an answer of 32 revolutions before the marks lined up...thank you for your post